# Get file descriptor if isatty(1) is 1

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I'm trying to determine if my program is being run in a noninteractive way.
So if execution looks like this `./foo.c <script.sh` how do i get script.sh and open it with a fopen? is this argv[1] and if it is, how do i get rid of "<"?

my current code

```
if(isatty(1) == 1)
     FILE *file;
     file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to, stdin (fd 0) is already open, so you can just read that, it's the default on getchar and gets (which you shouldn't use because of buffer overflow problems).  Using `<stdio.h>` then stin, stdout and sterr are pre-defined FILE *streams, so you can use safer functions like fgets, without opening file to stdin (or stdout).

It is the job of the POSIX shell to arrange the redirection, if foo is a program 
then `foo < script.sh` provides no arguments to `foo`.  argv[ 1] is the first argument to the 
command on the command line, in your example there's only an argv[ 0] defined.

If a non-interactive invocation, needs to read/write from terminal then /dev/tty can be opened.

Comment: How do you then read fd? `FILE *file = fopen(fd, "r");` like this?

Comment: so i do this? `while(fgets(line, sizeof(line))` and ignore the `file`

Comment: As I said, the shell redirection has opened script.sh for you, so you can either read from `stdin` with fgets/fgetc or simply read from the default which is fd 0, with getchar.  If you use fgets then #include <stdio.h> and put `stdin` in the fgets call for the FILE *stream parameter.